# Where should ReactDOM be imported from?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify

After upgrading to version `0.14.2`, I see an error and recommendation to use [`ReactDOM.render()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom) instead of `React.render()`, but whence do I import it?

When I don't import it and just running as it is, it shows it as `undefined`. Is it a built-in functionality or is it a 3rd party library?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

With the new update, all the DOM stuff you do should be done with `ReactDOM` instead of `React`. It's a separate module.

Do `npm install react-dom` and then, if you're using ES6, you can do:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

or if you're using ES5 you can just do:

```
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
```

and then you can use `ReactDOM.render()`, `ReactDOM.findDOMNode()`, etc in your code.

Comment: should use `import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'`?

Comment: @cyrilluce This was the syntax that worked for me using `"react": "^0.14.3"` and `"react-dom": "^0.14.3"`

Comment: `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'` should work just fine. You might need to do `import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'` if you're using TypeScript though.

Comment: Why do we need to use * as ReactDOM for typescript?

Answer (score 7):

if you are using the latest version of react (v18 onwards), the react and react statement has been updated. Earlier (till [v17.0.2](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#1702-march-22-2021) ) it was:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

currently (since [v18.0.0](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#1800-march-29-2022) ) it is:

```
import { React } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
```